# How does one get the height/width of an SVG group element?

Tags: svg

I need to know the width and height of a  SVG element? Im trying to use the following:

```
$('g#myGroup').height()
```

...but the result is always zero?

Answer (score 46):

svg `<g>` elements don't have explicit height and width attributes, they auto size to whatever they contain. You can get their actual height/width by calling getBBox on the element though:

```
var height = document.getElementById("myGroup").getBBox().height;
```

If you're really into jquery you could write it as

```
$('g#myGroup').get(0).getBBox().height;
```

according to Reed Spool

Comment: Perfect answer - might have used the jQuery version instead since OP is using that: $('g#myGroup').get(0).getBBox().height

Comment: @ReedSpool that's not the jQuery version. `.get` just returns the DOM element, jquery does not know about bbox.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer I was pointing out that `$().get()` could be used instead of the longer `document.getElementById()`, as the original question uses jQuery. Robert correctly incorporated my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to get any of the answers above to work, but did come across this solution for finding it with d3:

```
var height = d3.select('#myGroup').select('svg').node().getBBox().height;
var width = d3.select('#myGroup').select('svg').node().getBBox().width;
```

getBBox() here will find the actual width and height of the group element. Easy as that.

Comment: I tried with both getBBox() and getBoundingClientRect(). Both were showing fn is undefined. And the above answer working fine for me. Tx

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above answer, you can create jQuery functions .widthSVG() and .heightSVG()

```
/*
 * .widthSVG(className)
 * Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched SVG elements.
 */

$.fn.widthSVG = function(){
    return ($(this).get(0)) ? $(this).get(0).getBBox().width : null;
};

/*
 * .heightSVG(className)
 * Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched SVG elements.
 */
$.fn.heightSVG = function(){
    return ($(this).get(0)) ? $(this).get(0).getBBox().height : null;
};
```