# HTML <g> tag styling - NVD3

Tags: html, css, angularjs, svg, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 library to plot the PIE chart using angular. This is the output :

[image]

`svg` tag is of `width: 320px and height: 200px`. `<g>` element of html is not taking full width, I did not find `width` property on `<g>` element, i tried `stroke-width: 100%` but did not worked. I am trying to make `<g>` take full available width.

Chart config :

```
                 chart: {
                            type: 'pieChart',
                            height: height,
                            width: width,
                            x: function(d){return d.key;},
                            y: function(d){return d.y;},
                            showLabels: false,
                            duration: 500,
                            labelThreshold: 0.01,
                            labelSunbeamLayout: true,
                            legend: {
                                margin: {
                                    top: 5,
                                    right: 35,
                                    bottom: 5,
                                    left: 0
                                }
                            },
                            margin:{
                                left: 20
                            },
                           useInteractiveGuideline: true,    
                           interactive: true
                        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the pie chart elliptical? Looks like it's trying to maintain its h/w ratio at 1. You could try increasing the height of the <svg> element.

Comment: I added the cart configuration, increasing only height have same issue, if i had to increase both height and width to get legends in one line.

Comment: Changed legend right margin to 0 to make it better.

Comment: FYI g elements don't have a width or height. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620509/how-does-one-get-the-height-width-of-an-svg-group-element.

If you provide a plunkr/jsfiddle, it will help people debug.